# Printf outputs characters beyond the specified length of the array

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf, c-strings

I tried this chunk of code:

```
char string_one[8], string_two[8];
printf("&string_one == %p\n", &string_one);
printf("&string_two == %p\n", &string_two);
strcpy(string_one, "Hello!");
strcpy(string_two, "Long string");
printf("string_one == %s\n", string_one);
printf("string_two == %s\n", string_two);
```

And got this output:

```
&string_one == 0x7fff3f871524
&string_two == 0x7fff3f87151c
string_one == ing
string_two == Long string
```

Since the second string length value is greater than the specified size of the respective array, the characters which subscript values are greater than the specified array size are stored in the next bytes, which belong to the first array as the addresses show. Obviously the first string is overwritten.
There is no way the second array can hold the whole string, it is too big. Nevertheless, the output prints the whole string.
I speculated for a while and came to a conclusion that the `printf()` function keeps outputting characters from the next bytes until it comes across a string terminator `'\0'`. I did not find any confirmation for my pondering, so the question is are these speculations correct?

Comment: "the output prints the whole string." because code broke the rules with prior `strcpy(string_two, "Long string");` --> undefined behavior (UB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C Standard (5.2.1 Character sets)

> 2 In a character constant or string literal, members of the execution
> character set shall be represented by corresponding members of the
> source character set or by escape sequences consisting of the
> backslash \ followed by one or more characters. **A byte with all bits
> set to 0, called the null character, shall exist in the basic
> execution character set; it is used to terminate a character string.**

And (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **s** If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer
> to the initial element of an array of character type.273) **Characters
> from the array are written up to (but not including) the terminating
> null character.**

Comment: I assume that means yes

Answer (score 0):

My compiler(GCC) said:

> warning: ‘__builtin_memcpy’ writing 12 bytes into a region of size 8 overflows the destination [-Wstringop-overflow=]
> strcpy(string_two, "Long string");

Comment: Some compilers give an out-of-range warning, some do not. This is just a warning, if you know what it is about and what you are doing, there is nothing bad in getting it

Comment: Yes I know. My goal was to show that the null character was not written into the char array.

Comment: Of course it wasn't, the null subscript is greater than the specified array length

Answer (score 0):

And just to show how optimizations will take everything that *you think you know* and turn it on its head, here's what happens if you compile this on a 64-bit PowerPC Power-9 (aka not x86) with `gcc  -O3 -flto`

```
$ ./char-array-overlap
&string_one == 0x7fffc502bef0
&string_two == 0x7fffc502bef8
string_one == Hello!
string_two == Long string
```

Because if you look at the machine code it never executes `strcpy` at all.

Comment: Looks like you just swapped the addresses of the each string. That does not contradict my speculations, now the out-of-range characters are merely stored in `...bef9` and so on. These bytes do not belong to the first array anymore, therefore the first string is not overwritten.

Comment: @Kaiyaha I didn't swap anything. The compiler might have. There's no guarantees that local variables are in any particular order, or even in memory at all. In the code disassembly I looked at, those array addresses are never used for anything except to be printed out.

Comment: @Kaiyaha Ah that's interesting. On x86_64 it works as in the question even at O3. But on my Power-9 system it works just like in my answer. The powers of undefined behavior!

Comment: Didn't you mean that bytes are not necessarily ordered? I cannot find where a value goes if the next byte does not belong to anything I defined, somewhy it is not in the next address

Comment: @Kaiyaha The bytes are ordered. But there's no guarantee of order of string_one and string_two. And in the PowerPC machine code it doesn't do strcpy or use the arrays it executes the printf using the storage for the string literals. It optimizes out the copy to the array since the compiler knows the code is just a copy of the original value, so it simply uses the original value.

Comment: You didn't quite get my point, I asked about why can't I get access to a value when it is out of range and the excess values are not stored in another variable (array), that is when there is only one array defined